# What are the implications of using static positioning over absolute when making offscreen content for accessibility?

Tags: css, accessibility, wai-aria, wcag2.0

In creating alternatives to visual content to meet WCAG 2.0 guidelines, a common approach is to place an alternate display of content outside of the viewport so that it is readable to assistive technologies, but not present for sighted users.  The most cited examples typically look like:

```
.offscreen{
  position:absolute;
  left:-9999em;
}
```

With this approach, it's easy to end up in a situation where you have additional scrollbars on layout containers.  However, if fixed positioning is used it seems to eliminate the problem, as the offscreen content is no longer in the context of its container.  My question is, what are the potential pitfalls of using static positioning for offscreen accessible content?  My initial indication is that a screenreader would treat it the same as content that was positioned otherwise, but I have yet to find an example using static positioning. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to answer a different question than you asked. But partly because the CSS you have is what I suspect prompted the question. If you have scrollbars, then there is a problem that you rightly want to address.

The CSS you have is no longer ideal, [as explained by Graham Armfield](http://www.coolfields.co.uk/2016/05/text-for-screen-readers-only-updated/):

> ** Please Note ** This blog post was originally published in December 2009, and the stylesheet (CSS) technique I recommended at the time moved the screen reader text off the page to the left by setting `position:absolute;` and `left:-9999px;`
>
> That original definition still works for sites using left-to-right (LTR) languages, but is not compatible with right-to-left (RTL) languages – e.g. Hebrew, Arabic, etc. Recent testing on mobile Android devices using the Talkback screen reader has also shown that the original technique can lead to certain screen reader text elements in pages not being interpreted correctly, or not functioning correctly.
>
> A better definition presented here is compatible with languages in both directions – LTR and RTL, and works better for screen readers on mobile devices.

The updated CSS looks like this:

```
.screen-reader-text { 
   clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px); 
   height: 1px; 
   width: 1px; 
   overflow: hidden; 
   position: absolute !important;
}
```

[J. Renée Beach found an interesting issue](https://medium.com/@jessebeach/beware-smushed-off-screen-accessible-text-5952a4c2cbfe#.bazjjjus4) and adjusted the code a tiny bit, just adding one line to deal with a wrapping issue that caused screen readers to speak the text as one long word. Her code:

```
.accessible_elem {
  clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE 6/7 */
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap; /* added line */
  width: 1px;
}
```

My suggestion is to see if those work for you for that scrollbar problem.

As for your specific question, make a demo page, fire up a(ll the) screen reader(s), and see what you get.

Comment: +1 for testing with multiple screen readers and multiple browsers.  Don't forget VoiceOver on iOS.  When text is hidden off screen using the positioning CSS, iOS will scroll that offscreen content into view when it receives the VoiceOver focus, thus pushing out of view all the regular content.  It looks pretty bad.

Answer (score 0):

There's absolutely no implication on using one or another technique : **the pitfalls are the same.**

1. **Those techniques are based on the supposition that only blind people need accessibility**. People using that kind of hack often forget that those informations can benefit to people with cognitive or physical disabilities, including any other visual disability (e.g. color blindness).

*Best example of the misuse of this method is the "skip to content" link functionality which is very useful for keyboard-only users. (e.g. Parkinson disease)*

2. **People with low vision can use a screenreader but want to see which element is spoken thru the visual cursor**. Hiding the text while its read will give bad user experience.

*For instance, impossibility to click with the mouse a link which has been spoken*

3. Those methods sometimes suppose that blind people always use text-to-speech screenreaders while **they also can use braille display**. This can result in longer texts. Or even unintelligible text when using a phonetic replacement.

   ```
   ## Bad use: (will help screenreaders, but not braille display users)
   I have downloaded <span class="sr-only">oo-dacity</span>
        <span aria-hidden="true">Audacity</span>
   ```

### Screenreaders users represent 1% of the population. Accessibility targets 100%. If you think something is useful for blind people, it's useful for everyone.

*To answer your question: you're not missing anything but people nowadays prefer the `clip` method*

Comment: #1 - WebAIM.org has a nice implementation of 'skip to content' that works for both screen reader users and keyboard users.  When you tab, the skip link appears.  You never see it if you're a mouse user.   #2 - That's true, you can't click with the mouse on something you can't see but at least you can still hit ENTER to activate the link.  #3 - Excellent point.  Refreshable braille displays are often overlooked.  I have a bluetooth one for my iPad and it's awesome.

Comment: @slugolicious It won't work for eye tracking device, for instance. I really think about Stephen Hawking, whom device is somewhat specific, but we really can made the life easier for paralyzed people. Hitting "enter" already requires a keyboard when some people can use accessible touchscreen devices. I know I'm going against the tide, but the day we ban those naughty hacks we'll make people realize that accessibility does not concern 1% of the population.